# Running pages locally error: Could not find 'jekyll-watch' (~> 1.1) - did find: [jekyll-watch-2.2.1] (Gem::MissingSpecVersionError)

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

Trying to run github pages locally (minima theme) for a project page site, but can't sever the page. I think the issue has to do with jekyll, specifically "jekyll-watch" - whatever this is.

I have (..a long time ago..) managed to serve a different gitPage locally, so it might be a conflict of revisions. I have tried various cleanups & updates (see below).

```
    gem cleanup
```

You have requested to uninstall the gem: jekyll-3.4.3 depends on jekyll-watch (~> 1.1)

```
    gem install bundler
```

Successfully installed bundler-2.0.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 4 seconds
1 gem installed

```
    bundle install
```

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
make failed, exit code 1

```
    gem install jekyll-watch
```

1 gem installed

```
    **bundle exec jekyll serve**
```

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jekyll-watch":
  In Gemfile:
    github-pages x86-mingw32 was resolved to 139, which depends on
      jekyll (= 3.4.3) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 3.4.3, which depends on
        jekyll-watch (~> 1.1) x86-mingw32

Could not find gem 'jekyll-watch (~> 1.1)', which is required by gem 'jekyll (= 3.4.3)', in any of the sources.

**Any ideas how I can get serve to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue here is that you're not able to install native extensions.
**If you've installed Ruby via [RubyInstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/)**, first check your Ruby version:

```
ruby -v
```

If it is older than `2.4.0`, then I suggest installing a newer Ruby from the link above and ensure that you complete the step described in this [documentation](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2#install-gems-with-c-extensions-and-additional-library-dependencies).

---

Once you've setup Ruby properly, *update your Jekyll project* by running

```
bundle update
```

If you face issues with Bundler versions, delete existing `Gemfile.lock` and try again.

---

Note that your version of `github-pages` is very old. To avoid unexpected issues with `jekyll build`, lock your `Gemfile` to `github-pages-v139`

```rb
# Gemfile

gem "github-pages", "139", group: :jekyll_plugins
```

Then once you're sure that Ruby is able to install all the dependencies successfully, and that your site builds fine like before, consider updating the `github-pages` gem by removing the version constraint you placed in the Gemfile above.

Comment: I actually had 2.4.1, but updating to 2.6.3 solved my issue. Many thanks!